# How to archive a version of my repository on the online repository itself?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash

I know that `git archive` can create an archived file of the repository locally on the machine. I want to store it online on my repository.

For example, look at the following link:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/3.4.6.tar.gz

As you can see, the archive is stored on the git repository. How can I do that in gitlab or github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link points to a GitHub "release". The feature is present in Gitlab too, but at the moment, you can create Release entries via the Releases API only; it's recommended to do so as one of the last steps in your CI/CD release pipeline.

GitLab releases: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/index.html

GitHub releases: https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-releases

Comment: Looks like this is what I should look into. Thanks